Matplotlib pyplot y-axis ticks label to get more distant
matplotlib, object api in use to plot, plot type step
Low cardinality of y-axis variable. Two ticks that level too close to each other - their labels are visually joined. Attaching the screenshot presenting current look doesn't work. yaxis has 6 ticks over all for whole plot.
y-axis variable values is major information the plot communicates, along with timing (x-axis)
How to get labels of two ticks 137, 145 more distant from each another? Remaining ticks are placed at values 9, 41, 73, 201. yaxis is linear.
import sys, pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

reghist = pandas.Series( [ int(elem) for elem in  sys.stdin.read().split() ] )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.step(reghist.index.to_numpy(), reghist.values)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks(reghist.unique())
ax.arrow(0,0,reghist.size,0,head_width=10, head_length=10)
ax.tick_params(labelsize='xx-large', direction='in')
fig.savefig("lampsgetswitched.png")
fig.savefig("lampsgetswitched.svg")
plt.show()


As you are a new contributor on SO, you are not allowed to directly attach images to your post. Please upload the relevant images somewhere (e.g. on Google Drive) and edit the question to include a public link to the images. It will be easier for you to get relevant answers!

Not a Pandas boy (i.e., I cannot suggest a practical solution), but because your y-coordinates are essentially categories, you should tell Pandas to treat them as labels and not real numbers.
